# Want my iPhone app initially free and later user need to pay to continue using

Tags: iphone, subscription

I have developed an iPhone app, I want the app to be free for starting 10-15 days to the user & later I want the user to buy the subscription in order to continue using the app. What is the best way to implement this. Please guide me.

Comment: You can track newly registered users. Once user complete its free 15 days, force user to pay.

Comment: Thank you for your help!! As such there is no login process in the app, so what is the other way to track this ? and also, will Apple accept this process or they'll raise any flag ?

Comment: You can track with device UDID. You need to identify device or user in unique manner. After that only you can track and check.